# Identifying nth derivatives graphically

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have three functions below that are graphed. I don't know what they are, but the red looks like a sine function, the green looks like a cosine function. However, because of what the blue function looks like it seems neither red or green are sine or cosine functions because I know the first and second order derivatives for them look nothing like the blue one.

So, how do I identify $w(x), w'(x), \text{ and } w''(x)$? I've exhausted all my attempts at solving this problem to get points, but even a hint would be nice.

> [image]

Comment: Maybe you are overthinking. Function A is positive. So, if it were a derivative, then its antiderivative should be a strictly increasing function. There is no such function, hence, A is $w(x)$. The remaining part consists in just looking at the local extrema.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now

Comment: If you rewrite that as an answer I'll accept it as one

Comment: ok. will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are overthinking.

Function A is positive. So, if it were a derivative, then its antiderivative should be a strictly increasing function.

There is no such function, hence, A is w(x).

The remaining part consists in just looking at the local extrema.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Clearly each of the graphs has horizontal tangents, so each of the three functions has points where the derivative is $0$. This makes it easy to see that one of the functions cannot be the derivative of either of the others and must therefore be $w(x)$; which one is it?

Once you’ve identified that, look for the places where its derivative is $0$; only one of the other two functions is $0$ at those places, so that one must be $w'(x)$.

Comment: Well, the slope of the minimum/maximum of the red function at point $k$ is equal to 0, and I see that $C(k)=0$. I also notice that the slope of the minimum/maximum of the blue function at point $p$ is equal to $B(p)$. I'm not sure how to extend from this though, like, I'm overthinking which one is the first or second derivative

Comment: @Lex_i: None of that has much to do with the hint that I gave, and it’s not at all clear what $k$ you have in mind.

Comment: Ok so take $\approx A(3/2)$, the slope at that point is 0. It's also the case that $B(3/2)=0$. So am I supposed to think that A is $w(x)$, B is $w'(x)$, and C is $w''(x)$?

Comment: @Lex_i: The fact that $A$ has slope $0$ at $3/2$ and $B$ **is** $0$ at $3/2$ is certainly consistent with the possibility that $A$ is the graph of $w(x)$ and $B$ the graph of $w'(x)$, but it’s also consistent with the possibility that $A$ is the graph of $w'(x)$ and $B$ the graph of $w''(x)$. The first question in the hint eliminates one of these possibilities; which one, and why?